# First In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to add my first in-app purchase to my iOS application

It's state in iTunesConnect is "Missing Metadat", but the only thing I didn't send is the screenshot for the review (I expect to see "Wiating for screenshot" instead of "missing metadata"). I also specified the localization name of its group

The thing is that in my application, my productIdentifier appears in the invalid products, and I don't know why because it seems for me that everything is fine.

I disconnected my AppStore account, My AppID and my signInProfiles have In-App Purchase checked in the capabilities, XCode does not show any error in the project's settings, I have a sandbox user on iTunesConnect.

I really don't understand what to do to make things working...

Note : A few months earlier, I managed to have an In-app product and I was able to test it on my application in the development state. We didn't submit it to the App Review and I had to delete it from iTunesConnect.

Comment: Check for your in-app purchase in your developer account whether have submitted it for review.

Comment: I didn't send it to review, I've read it a lot, but in the Apple's official documentation say (pretty strongly) that we don't have to do that for the first IAP, and that it's juste an urban legend

Comment: Then i think need to find reason why IAP is appearing in invalid product. That will most probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of my problem

I apologize because I totaly forgot to talk about it, but I work with 3 stagings of my application : Production, Integration (i.e BETA), Development
And to be able to have all 3 of them on my devices, I use extensions in my appIDs for each state :
- com.compagny.app for production
- com.compagny.app.integration for integration
- com.compagny.app.dev for develpment

And it seems that for IAPs YOU HAVE TO keep the exact same appID as it is on iTunesConnect... :/ That was just that...

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate it actually can't get you.